# How can I prove that inline functions default to internal linkage?

Tags: c++, linkage

How can I prove that inline functions iin class default to internal linkage?

In other words/:

How can I display output of internal linkage to console?

EDIT: unix platform

Comment: It seems to me you might misunderstand what internal linkage is:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358400/what-is-external-linkage-and-internal-linkage-in-c

Comment: Just for your information,
7.1.2/3 footnote says
_The inline keyword has no effect on the linkage of a function_.
So, I think inline functions aren't defaulted to internal linkage particularly.

Comment: You can't because they don't. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540931/

Comment: @Charles: This should be an answer - it's spot on.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is an FAQ about inline functions http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/inline-functions.html.

Comment: Posting a link is not an answer to the question, even if it is relevant. If you have the answer it's better to write it directly down

Comment: I thought the very point of a Frequently Asked Question is to answer that once so you don't have to give the same answer again and again.

Comment: The linked FAQ fails to mention linkage, which makes this discussion moot. -1

Comment: No, they don't. It's about inline functions. It explains what inline functions are, which should clarify that there is no connection between inline functions and internal linkage.