# C++ circular dependency between multiple classes

Tags: c++, circular-dependency

I have the following 3 classes: A, B and C. I got errors for circular dependency for `random_int()`, how can I resolve the following circular dependency?

3x Error: function random_int() is already defined in main.cpp.
Files: C.cpp, A.cpp and B.cpp

A.hpp

```
#include "B.hpp"

int random_int() {

class C
class A {
    public: 
        void set_b(B& be) {b = be}
        B* get_b() {return b;}

        static A& getInstance()
        {
            static A instance;
            return instance;
        }
    private:
        B* b;
        test();
}
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.hpp"
#include "C.hpp"

void test() {
    if (dynamic_cast<C*>(obj)) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

B.hpp

```
class C;
class B {
    public:
        std::vector<C*> nearby_cs*(C& obj);  
}
```

B.cpp

```
#include "B.hpp"
#include "C.hpp"

std::vector<C*> B::nearby_cs*(C& obj) {
//do stuff
}
```

C.hpp

```
class A
class C {
    void stuff();
}
```

C.cpp

```
#include "C.hpp"
#include "A.hpp"

void stuff() {
    std::vector<C*> cs = A::getInstance().get_b()->nearby_cs(*this);
}
```

Comment: And what exactly led you to conclude that the problem here is a "circular dependency" and not, say, attempting to assign a reference to a pointer?

Comment: _"I got errors"_.  Errors usually describe what the problem is.  May we see these errors?

Comment: Are you missing some braces and semicolons there? Plese provide a [mcve] and do not keep the error messages to yourself

Comment: AFAIK, `std::vector<C*> B::nearby_cs*(C& obj)` is not a valid function declaration.

Comment: In `A.hpp` you have 2 typos. Replace `{` with a semicolon and add a semicolon after `class C`. Also there should be a semicolon after `class A` in `C.hpp`. There should be semicolons after classes declarations, as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function already defined error in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964819/function-already-defined-error-in-c)

Comment: This seems to be a case of **writing too much code before testing**.  Just including A.hpp will result in several typo-related errors.  The existence of other headers doesn't matter.

Comment: @DrewDormann Exactly. To the OP: In cases like this, comment out a lot of the code (around 50%) and try again. If the error persists, it's in the remaining code; if not, in the commented out part. Divide the respective part again etc.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
int random_int() {

class C
```

to this

```
int random_int();

class C;
```

I presume the `{` and missing `;` are simply typos.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

`3x Error: function random_int() is already defined in main.cpp. Files: C.cpp, A.cpp and B.cpp` is not a problem caused because of a circular dependency, it is caused because you're defining the `random_int()` three times. It doesn't have anything to do with the classes.

**Solution:**

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964819/function-already-defined-error-in-c), the possible solutions for your problem are:

1. Declare the function as static.

- A.hpp

```cpp
   static int random int()
   {
      ...
   }
```

2. Declare the function as inline.

- A.hpp

```cpp
   inline int random int()
   {
      ...
   }
```

3. Declare the function in the header (`.hpp`) file and define it in a source (`.cpp`) file.

- A.hpp

```cpp
   ...
   int random_int();
   ...
```

- A.cpp

```cpp
   ...
   int random_int(){
      ...
   }
   ...
```

**Additional information:**

1. You have multiple typos with semicolons and braces.