# OBJ_Loader.h linking error when included in multiple files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors, objloader

I am using [OBJ-Loader](https://github.com/Bly7/OBJ-Loader/tree/master/Source) to load **.obj**. For my project, I need to include the *OBJ_Loader.h* in multiple files. It gives me the **LNK2005** linking error on visual studio. It says something like "the object file is already defined". But if I include it twice in a single file, it works okay.

Comment: Edit the header and add `inline` to the free functions that are missing it. This looks to be an [old issue](https://github.com/Bly7/OBJ-Loader/issues/17) once fixed but now [returned](https://github.com/Bly7/OBJ-Loader/issues/28).

Comment: Do you mean every single function that doesn't have it, including the overloaded operators?

Comment: Just the [free functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861914/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-term-free-function-in-c). Member functions defined inside the class are implicitly inline.

Comment: It works! But can you please explain what is happening?

Comment: From the [LNK2005](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2005?view=msvc-160) page: "*This error can occur when a header file defines a function that isn't inline. If you include this header file in more than one source file, you get multiple definitions of the function in the executable. [...] Possible solutions include: Add the inline keyword to the function: [...]*". Some more details under the question I proposed as a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964819/function-already-defined-error-in-c).

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, I would appreciate it if you could write them as answer and mark them. Because this will be beneficial to other community.