# Link-time optimization and inline

Tags: c++, c, optimization, gcc

In my experience, there's lot of code that explicitly uses inline functions, which comes at a tradeoff:

1. The code becomes less succinct and somewhat less maintainable.
2. Sometimes, inlining can greatly increase run-time performance.
3. Inlining is decided at a fixed point in time, maybe without a terribly good foreknowledge of its uses, or without considering all (future) surrounding circumstances.

The question is: does link-time optimization (e.g., in GCC) render manual inlining, e.g., declaring in C99 a function "inline" and providing an implementation, obsolete? Is it true that we don't need to consider inlining for most functions ourselves? What about functions that do *always* benefit from inlining, e.g., deg_to_rad(x)?

*Clarification:* I am not thinking about functions that are in the same translation-unit anyway, but about functions that should logically reside in different translation-units.

*Update:* I have often seen an opposition against "inline", and it was suggested obsolete. Personally, however, I do see explicitly inlined functions often: as functions defined in a class body.

Comment: Note that there's no such thing as "functions that always benefit from inlining".  If your `deg_to_rad` is called many times in many different places in the code, it will greatly inflate the code size which can lead to caching/paging issues.

Comment: Declaring a function `inline` is pretty much a no-op. A good compiler will ignore the keyword for inlining decisions and make its own choice about whether to inline.

Comment: @Oli, actually I chose the example b/c calling deg_to_rad would usually take more instructions (store, call, load) than just multiplying a float.

Comment: @R, actually, in C99, this is not permitted.

Comment: @ccom: Huh? It's always up to the discretion of the compiler if it performs some optimization or not. And programmer annotated `inline`'s are pretty much ignored on any modern compiler, and rightly so.

Comment: @GMan Have you tested that? From the assembly output I've looked at, it seems MSVC takes `inline` pretty seriously.

Comment: `inline` has semantic as well as optimization effects.  I don't remember exactly what they are, but it is definitely possible to construct a strictly conforming program that would trigger constraint violations if you removed all instances of the keyword.

Comment: @Crash: [This says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88.aspx): "The insertion (called inline expansion or inlining) occurs only if the compiler's cost/benefit analysis show it to be profitable." What code are you testing?

Comment: @Zack: It effectively says "ignore duplicates of this function", so you can have a definition of a function included in multiple translation units without error. (Note the context of this question is with optimization, though.)

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: You are assuming that the instruction count of the call is smaller than the instruction count of the function. inlining `int add(int x,int y) {return x+y;}` will always be beneficial as not only the cost of the call but the instruction count to make the call is higher than the cost of the function body. I think deg_rad() also falls into this category as it is very simple.

Comment: @GMan, I was writing non-sense, of course the compiler might just issue a call to the external definition, or just not take the hint.

Comment: @Crashworks: It may look that way but unless you force it too the compiler will ignore you. Humans are **very** bad at this kind of optimization compilers are **very** good at this. Thus they normally ignore you and do what is best for the application.

Comment: @Martin : People often tell me this, but I often find that the C++ compiler generates less than ideal code. In fact, most of my job consists of improving performance in realtime code by finding places where the compiler did the wrong thing, and fixing them.

Comment: @GMan A math library for SIMD operations on vectors, quaternions, and matrices, to start with.

Comment: @Crashworks: I was thinking on stuff like that.

Comment: I have often seen what Crashworks has seen. Between a lack of runtime knowledge and perfect CPU architecture knowledge it is impossible for the compiler to make consistently optimal inlining decisions. It's difficult for Humans too, but strictly speaking, not impossible, especially when focusing on a small piece of critical code.

Comment: @Crashworks: As a compiler writer. Then you must be using some pretty ancient compilers. The ones I have worked on find this task relatively simple task that is imposable to get wrong.

Comment: Since you disagree on the most fundamental issue (which is what my question was about), could you give (more detailed) examples/proof?

Comment: @Martin: Are you saying that compilers can always inline, when they want to, or that they always make the right decision?  LTO certainly allows the former these days, but the latter is not something any compiler technology can claim.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth inlining's benefit is not limited to the elimination of the subroutine call; inlining opens up a lot of other optimizations (code transformations) not possible without inlining. Often those other optimizations dominate the benefit.

Comment: @LokiAstari We trust the compiler's inlining heuristics to be correct 99% of the time, but Crashworks would be talking about proverbial "the 1% of code that accounts for 99% of the execution time" example. In other words, there is a 1% of code where a programmer finds necessary to override the compiler's heuristics (after extensive benchmarking and examination of the disassembly), but the same programmer will be satisfied with entrusting the remaining 99% of the code to the compiler's inlining heuristics.

Answer (score 14):

Even with LTO, a compiler still has to use heuristics to determine whether or not to inline a function for every **call** (note it makes the decision not per function, but per call).  The heuristic takes into account factors like - is it in a loop, is the loop unrolled, how big the function is, how frequently it is called globally, etc.  The compiler will certainly never be able to accurately determine how frequently code is called, and whether or not the code expansion is likely to blow out the instruction/trace/loop/microcode caches of a particular CPU at compile time.

Profile Guided Optimization is supposed to be a step towards addressing this, but if you've ever tried it, you are likely to have noticed that you can get a swing in performance in the order of 0-2%, and it can be in either direction! :-)  It's still a work in progress.

If performance is your ultimate goal, and you really know what you are doing, and really do a thorough analysis of your code, what one really needs is a way to tell the compiler to inline or not inline on a per-call basis, **not** a per-function hint.  In practice I have managed this by using compiler specific "force_no_inline" type hints for cases I don't want inlining, and a separate "force_inline" copy (or macro in the rare case this fails) of the function for when I want it inlined.  If anyone knows how to do this in a cleaner way with compiler specific hints (for any C/C++ compilers), please let me know.

To specifically address your points:

> > 1.The code becomes less succinct and somewhat less maintainable.

Generally, no - it's just a keyword hint that controls how it is inlined.  However if you jump through hoops like I described in the last paragraph, then yes.

> > 2.Sometimes, inlining can greatly increase run-time performance.

When leaving the compiler to its own devices - yes, it certainly can, but mostly doesn't.  The compiler has good heuristics that make good although not always optimal inlining decisions.  Specificially for the keyword, compilers may totally ignore the keyword, or use to keyword as a weak hint - in general they do seem adverse to inlining code that red flags their heuristics (like inlining a 16k function into a loop unrolled 16x).

> > 3.Inlining is decided at a fixed point in time, maybe without a terribly good foreknowledge of its uses, or without considering all (future) surrounding circumstances.

Yes, it uses static analysis.  Dynamic analysis can come from your insight and **you** manually controlling inlining on a per-call basis, or theoretically from PGO (which still sucks).

Comment: Since you have an elaborate inline-system in place, how do you check if the compiler did inline a particular function call?

Comment: I would also be very interested in how to give the compiler the hint to inline a single function call.

Comment: Really oldschool: I look at the code generated by using objdump for gcc or .asm output for msvc to see what was actually generated.  I also have some scripts the pipe the objdum -d output through grep "call" and wc, in order to get a total call count.  Assuming the function you are trying to inline (or not inline) has less than or more than 1 call count you can get quick feedback on whether or not your code change made a difference.

Comment: Cool. I wonder if can be done with gdb, or another debugger/profiler.

Answer (score 10):

**GCC 9 Binutils 2.33 experiment to show that LTO can inline**

For those that are curious if `ld` inlines across object files or not, here is a quick experiment that confirms that it can:

main.c

```
int notmain(void);

int main(void) {
    return notmain();
}
```

notmain.c

```
int notmain(void) {
    return 42;
}
```

Compile with LTO and disassemble:

```
gcc -O3 -flto -ggdb3 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c -o main.o main.c
gcc -O3 -flto -ggdb3 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c -o notmain.o notmain.c
gcc -O3 -flto -ggdb3 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.out notmain.o main.o
gdb -batch -ex "disassemble/rs main" main.out
```

Disassembly output:

```
   0x0000000000001040 <+0>:     b8 2a 00 00 00  mov    $0x2a,%eax
   0x0000000000001045 <+5>:     c3      retq
```

so we see that there is no `callq` or other jumps, which means that the call was inlined across the two object files.

Without `-flto` however we see:

```
   0x0000000000001040 <+0>:     f3 0f 1e fa     endbr64 
   0x0000000000001044 <+4>:     e9 f7 00 00 00  jmpq   0x1140 <notmain>
```

so how there is a JMPQ, which means that the call was not inlined.

Note that the compiler chose JMPQ which does not make any stack changes as would be done by a more naive CALLQ as an optimization, I think this is a trivial minimal case of a [tail call optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization/55230417#55230417).

So yes, if you are using `-flto`, you don't need to worry about putting definitions in headers so they can be inlined.

The main downside of having definitions in headers is that they may slow down compilation. For C++ templates, you may also be interested in explicit template instantiation: [Explicit template instantiation - when is it used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351148/explicit-template-instantiation-when-is-it-used/59614755#59614755)

Tested in Ubuntu 19.10 amd64.

Answer (score 5):

> The question is: does link-time optimization (e.g., in GCC) render
>   manual inlining, e.g., declaring in C99 a function "inline" and
>   providing an implementation, obsolete?

[This article](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=243) would seem to answer "Yes:"

> Think for a minute: what turns a function into a good candidate for
>   inlining? Apart from the size factor, the optimizer needs to know how
>   often this function is called, where it is called from, how many other
>   functions in the program are viable candidates for inlining and --
>   believe it or not -- whether the function is ever called. Optimizing
>   (i.e. inlining) a function that isn't called even once is a waste of
>   time and resources. But how can an optimizer know that a function is
>   never called? Well, it cannot. Unless it has scanned the entire
>   program. This is where [link-time optimization] becomes crucial.

Comment: Of course, LTO is necessary for making "inline" obsolete, the question is if it is obsolete in real-life.

Comment: Unfortunately, the article is mostly speculative, and was written when LTO wasn't as common-place as it is today.

Comment: "The question is: does link-time optimization render manual inlining obsolete." There is no "real life" in the question. Manual inlining is effectively a compiler hint, anyway. LTO allows compiler and linker to make a much more informed choice about what to inline.

Comment: Also, the article explains how LTO (aka WPO) operates in "Visual C++ 7.0 and later versions, including the most recent Visual C++ 2005 beta 2." How is that speculative? If it's in a beta, it has been implemented.

Comment: I guess, I should put "real life" in the question. However, since a perfect compiler and optimizer renders the whole discussion and question void, it's already implicit.

Comment: The article is speculative insofar it mentions benefits without providing real data or comparisons. It's actually confusing that he tries to focus on Visual C++ when most of what writes is valid generally to LTO/PGO. It looks like he didn't study the compiling techniques he mentions, and did not run quantitative tests. He fails to mention that PGO does not always improve speed b/c many aspects of it are still up to research. Statements like "[...] my impression that there's still room for improvement" are just biased opinions, and some parts just read like an ad.

Answer (score 1):

If link time optimization were as fast as compile time optimization, then it would obviate the need for compiler hints. Unfortunately, it is generally not faster than compile time optimization, so it's a tradeoff between overall build speed and the overall quality of optimizations for that build.

Also, you still need to use inline when defining functions in headers. Otherwise, you will get linker errors for multiple definitions of those functions if they are used in multiple translation units.

Comment: That's a valid comment. But is "inline" really obsolete when LTO is assumed to be enabled?

Comment: "Otherwise, you will get linker errors for multiple definitions of those functions if they are used in multiple translation units" -- the `static` keyword is what is needed here.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't think the inline keyword affects maintainability, and only barely the succinctness.  (opinion)
2. Sometimes inline can decrease run-time performance : http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/inline-functions.html#faq-9.3
3. The compilers are quite smart about inlining, I've heard that Visual Studio ignores them almost completely and decides inlining itself.

`does link-time optimization render manual inlining, obsolete?`
Not at all, the optimizer that makes the inline keyword nigh-obsolete kicks in way before link-time.

Comment: The optimizer that could make inline obsolete cannot kick in before link-time, b/c the definition may not be (and would in most interesting cases) in the same translation unit.

Comment: Regarding 2: That's why I put a "sometimes" in it and have "3".

Comment: `inline` doesn't necessarily tell the compiler that the function must be inlined; most modern compilers ignore that and use it only to specify that the function has internal linkage.

Comment: @Billy: `inline` doesn't give a function internal linkage, `static` does. That said, the *effect* is often the same, but implementation-wise it's not.

Comment: @Billy inline also means the compiler shouldn't throw errors if the function is defined multiple times, is that what you were thinking of?

Comment: @Mooing: That's what internal linkage is, yes.

Comment: @Billy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957582/how-can-i-prove-that-inline-functions-default-to-internal-linkage `7.1.2/3 footnote says The inline keyword has no effect on the linkage of a function.`

Comment: @Billy: No, that's not what internal linkage is.

Answer (score -2):

Item 33 - Scott Myers - 2nd Ed - Effective C++ springs to mind.

You must bear in mind the keyword static wrt inline! Now there is a hornets nest!

Comment: Would you care to share what that Item says, for those of us without that book?

Comment: @Oli: Particularly when that item # is from an obsolete edition... :)