# Concatenating strings (and numbers) in variadic template function

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I am attempting to write a function that takes a variety of strings or numbers (that work with `std::to_string` and concatenate them. I've got it working with just strings, but I am having trouble with specializing depending on input as string or number.

My code is called like this:

`stringer("hello", "world", 2, 15, 0.2014, "goodbye", "world")`

And here is what I've got:

```
inline std::string stringer(const std::string &string)
{
    return string;
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
inline std::string stringer(const std::string &string, T &&val, Args &&...args)
{  
    return stringer(string+std::to_string(val), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <typename... Args>
inline std::string stringer(const std::string &string, Args &&...args)
{
    return stringer(string, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Currently it is breaking on any more than one string added unless the following are all numbers (due to the to_string). How can I specialize based on string or number to make the above work? Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
inline std::string const& to_string(std::string const& s) { return s; }

template<typename... Args>
std::string stringer(Args const&... args)
{
    std::string result;
    using ::to_string;
    using std::to_string;
    int unpack[]{0, (result += to_string(args), 0)...};
    static_cast<void>(unpack);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I receive error: call of overloaded ‘to_string’ on gcc, and errors on clang as well

Comment: [Works like a charm once you let the custom to_string be visible](http://ideone.com/gGZhPd). I was going to post my solution that's what you actually asked (specialize on whether `to_string(x)` succeeds) but this is much shorter and elegant.

Comment: @DanielKO Thanks, d'oh. Would you mind posting your solution just for completeness? While this answers my goal I could still learn a thing from yours

Comment: @simple what would the static_cast be doing here?

Comment: @jett it avoids "unused variable" warnings.

Comment: I love Simple answers =)

Comment: For an even simpler answer: in the case of many compilers (e.g gcc + clang) you can additionally ditch the `static_cast` line if you define `unpack` with an unused attribute, like this: `int unpack[] __attribute__((unused)) {0, (out += to_string(args), 0)...};`

Comment: Is `int unpack[]` actually constructed every time or compiler is smart enough to only leave side effects?
It's a shame that you can't just do (expression involving pack)... that'd just translate to (expression with first param), (expression with second param), etc.

Answer (score 17):

Why do not use simple std::stringstream ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

template< typename ... Args >
std::string stringer(Args const& ... args )
{
    std::ostringstream stream;
    using List= int[];
    (void)List{0, ( (void)(stream << args), 0 ) ... };

    return stream.str();
}

int main()
{
    auto s = stringer("hello", ' ', 23, ' ', 3.14, " Bye! " );

    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Very nice solution. I initially tried to use a stringstream but was having trouble doing it "in place", this makes it a lot more clear- thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of the `(/* do stuff with args*/, 0)` syntax? Since it's comma operator, it will take the right hand portion of the expression for each item in the variadic parameter? Essentially creating an array of zeros? Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @Khurshid Why it goes `{(0, ((stream << args), 0), 0) ...}`? What happens there?

Comment: @romanp: This call creates a (compile-time) recursive initialization list construction to create an unused, unnamed, dummy `int` array, but the expression `( (void)(stream << args), 0 )` has the side-effect of streaming the args into the stream (before returning the second `0`).

Comment: This is an amazing solution, does anyone have a resource that talks about clever stuff like this?

Answer (score 7):

Three more ways to do this:

1. Similar to Khurshid's but without unnecessary array of ints
2. Similar to Simple's and Khurshid's but builds on older compilers
3. Recurent way

And the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

// First version:
template<typename T>
std::string toString(T value)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << value;
    return oss.str();
}

std::string merge(std::initializer_list<std::string> strList)
{
    std::string ret = "";
    for (std::string s : strList) {
        ret += s;
    }
    return ret;
}

template< typename ... Args >
std::string stringer1(const Args& ... args)
{
    return merge({toString(args)...});
}


// Second version:
template< typename ... Args >
std::string stringer2(const Args& ... args)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    int a[] = {0, ((void)(oss << args), 0) ... };

    return oss.str();
}


// Third version:
template<typename T>
std::string stringer3(const T& value)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << value;
    return oss.str();
}

template<typename T, typename ... Args >
std::string stringer3(const T& value, const Args& ... args)
{
    return stringer3(value) + stringer3(args...);
}

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    std::cout << stringer1("a", 1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << stringer2("b", 2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << stringer3("c", 3) << std::endl;

// Output:
//     a1
//     b2
//     c3
}
```

Comment: This seems less efficient - we create a new `stringstream` for every object we need to convert, then we use `string`'s `+=` operator which continuously reassigns memory.

Answer (score 6):

With C++17 we now have [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) to simplify this:

```
#include <sstream>

// cat - Concatenate values of arbitrary types into a string.
template <typename... Ts>
std::string cat(Ts&&... args) {
  std::ostringstream oss;
  (oss << ... << std::forward<Ts>(args));
  return oss.str();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Per request, here's a (longer) solution with SFINAE:

```
namespace detail {
    using std::to_string;

    std::string
    concat()
    {
        return "";
    }

    template<typename Head, typename... Tail>
    decltype( to_string(std::declval<Head>()) )
    concat(Head&& h, Tail&&... t);

    template<typename Head, typename... Tail>
    decltype(std::string() + std::declval<Head>())
    concat(Head&& h, Tail&&... t)
    {
        return std::forward<Head>(h) + concat(std::forward<Tail>(t)...);
    }

    template<typename Head, typename... Tail>
    decltype( to_string(std::declval<Head>()) )
    concat(Head&& h, Tail&&... t)
    {
        return to_string(std::forward<Head>(h)) + concat(std::forward<Tail>(t)...);
    }
}

template<typename... Args>
std::string concat(Args&&... args)
{
    return detail::concat(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Can be seen in action here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77e27eaabc97b86b

Note that it assumes, for a given type, either string concatenation (with `+`) or `to_string()` is defined, but not both. So `std::string`, `const char*` and any 3rd party string class that interacts naturally with `std::string` should go through the `+` version. Of course, if the 3rd party string class does something silly like defining both concatenation and `to_string()` this will be ambiguous; you would need to define `has_string_concat` and `has_to_string` type predicates to have control on how to resolve the ambiguity.

I'm also putting everything in a namespace to be able to use argument-dependent lookup to select the right version of `to_string`; the full example shows a user-defined type with its own `to_string()`.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ 11, doing it in variadic templates way works for me. It also enforces user to provide at least one argument. `inline` is helpful if you are defining functions in header file.

```
#include <sstream>

template< typename T >
inline std::string stringify(const T& t)
{
    std::stringstream string_stream;
    string_stream << t;
    return string_stream.str();
}

template< typename T, typename ... Args >
inline std::string stringify(const T& first, Args ... args)
{
    return stringify( first ) + stringify( args... );
}
```

Comment: _"`inline` is helpful if you are defining functions in header file."_ No, it adds nothing, because template functions are implicitly inline anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527415/are-methods-of-templated-classes-implied-inline-linkage