# A variadic function that accepts Strings and Ints, Format the latter and concatenate all?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I'm trying to use the answer from DanielKO in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21806561/concatenating-strings-and-numbers-in-variadic-template-function) for my needs but i'm not familiar with templates and variadic functions, and i don't get what should i do.

What i'd need is a variadic c++(11) function which i can call like this:

```
 String NewMsg = CreateMessage("SET",16,1,17,0,"RED",47);
```

and have NewMsg= "SET,0010,0001,0011,0000,RED,002F".

I'm not even able to get where should i add the comma between the arguments.
And then:
How could i distinguish between integers and string while parsing the args, so to format each integer to hexadecimal strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing other two solutions (the recursive one from Passer By and the C++17 fold expression one from Nick Mertin), you can write `CreateMessage()` without recursion (in a simil-fold expression way) also in C++11

```
std::string const & getStr (std::string const & ret)

 { return ret; }

std::string getStr (int val)
 {
   std::ostringstream ret;

   ret << std::hex << std::setw(4) << std::setfill('0') << val;

   return ret.str();
 }

template <typename ... Ts>
std::string CreateMessage (Ts const & ... args)
 {
   using unused = int[];

   std::string ret   = "";
   std::string comma = "";

   (void)unused { 0, ( ret += comma + getStr(args), comma = ",", 0 )... };

   return ret;
 }
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP asks

> Would you like to teach me how that "simil-fold" line works? How should i "read" it?

Well... the line is the following

```
(void)unused { 0, ( ret += comma + getStr(args), comma = ",", 0 )... };
```

where `unused` is an alias (`using`) for `int[]`.

It uses the fact that a variadic pack (template or function arguments) can be expanded in the context of a C-style array initialization and also uses the power of the comma operator (the propriety of comma operator of exec/compute and discard what is on the left of the comma).

So you have the expansion (for every argument in `args...`) of

```
( ret += comma + getStr(args), comma = ",", 0 )
```

where

1) you add `comma + getStr(args)` to `ret`, where `comma` is empty for first argument and equal to `","` (see (2)) for the following arguments

2) the first comma operator discard the value of `ret` and assign `","` to `comma` (so you have an empty `comma` in first `ret +=` and `","` for followings `ret +=`

3) the second comma operator discard the value of comma and return 0 to the initialization of `unuses`

So `ret` is incremented with all `getStr(args)` separated by `","` and the unused array is initialized with zeros.

Observe another couple of points:

a) in the array (the un-named `unused`) initialization list, you have a starting and not variadic related zero (`{ 0,`); this is necessary in case the `args...` list is empty, so the line become `(void)unsed { 0 };`, that is legal, instead of `(void)unused { };` (without that zero) that is a syntax error

b) `unused` is preceded by `(void)`; this isn't strictly necessary but useful to avoid a warning of type "object defined but not used".

Comment: This solution worked out of the box, thanks.
Would you like to teach me how that "simil-fold" line works? How should i "read" it?

Comment: @Parduz - answer improved; hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

You use recursion and function overloading

```
std::string CreateMessage(int i)
{
    return /* i formatted as hex */;
}

std::string CreateMessage(const char* s)
{
    return s;
}

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
std::string CreateMessage(T t, Ts... ts)
{
    return CreateMessage(t) + "," + CreateMessage(ts...);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use recursion with templates, as Passer By did in his answer. However, in my opinion a more elegant solution (if you are able to use C++17 lanugage features) is to use a [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) to avoid recursion. The expression is expanded such that `Append` is called directly for each argument, sort of like a for-loop across the arguments evaluated at compile time.

```
template <class T>
void Append(std::ostringstream &out, T &&arg) {
    out << "," << std::forward<T>(arg);
}

template <class... TArgs>
std::string CreateMessage(TArgs &&...args) {
    std::ostringstream out;
    (Append(out, std::forward<TArgs>(args)), ...);
    return out.str().substr(1);
}
```

Live demo [here](https://onlinegdb.com/ryD42qnQV).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of a "fold expression" and how that "Append" works.

But i only use C++11.