# Can the default C++ std::allocator be supplanted/superseded for 3rd party libraries?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, stl, c++17

My team is working on an application, where we need to track memory usage, and provide statistics on how much memory areas of the program utilize (e.g. N bytes used by uncontrolled STL containers).  I need to find a way to identify memory allocated in 3rd party libs from STL containers.

The application makes use of 3rd party libraries that either we don't have access to the source code, or have been directed not to make changes to the source.  Some of these libraries use standard STL containers, `like std::vector<int>`, but they have used (or appear to use, in the case of the closed libs) the default `std::allocator`.  We are targeting Windows, with future work planned for Mac and Linux platforms, using C++17 as much as possible.

I've overridden the `malloc` and `free` functions; overridden `new`, `new[]`, `delete` and `delete[]` operators; and created an `STLAllocator` class derived from `std::allocator` that is used as the `_Alloc` template parameter for our use of STL containers.  For the libraries that provide hooks to replace the memory allocators, I have done so.  When the STL containers in the remaining 3rd partly libs use the default `std::allocator`, I can see their `new` and `delete` calls come through the `new` and `delete` overrides, but these appear no different to tracking than a call to `new` or `delete` made from `main`.

I've read many great descriptions of how to declare and use your own `std::allocator` class, been reminded of the template parameter equality issue when providing different allocators, and made aware of an upcoming solution using `std::experimental::pmr::polymorphic_allocator`, but I haven't found a definitive answer to my question. Is there a way to supplant the default `std::allocator` for 3rd party libs that don't provide a hook to override the default `std::allocator` used by STL containers?

For anyone interested, here is the link that describes the template parameter equality issue; it's also a good overview of std::allocator in general:
https://blog.feabhas.com/2019/03/thanks-for-the-memory-allocator/

Comment: You can modify all `new` expressions in the main application to use a custom overload of `operator new` and distinguish them from library code that way if that is an acceptable solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is more of a general-purpose tracking, and is not supposed to impose overloading new and delete for each class.

Comment: @walnut, Ah, sorry, I misunderstood what you meant.  Yeah, as mentioned above, I've already overloaded `new`, `new[]`, `delete` and `delete[]`.  The issue with this solution is that `std::alllocator` calls `new`, which comes through the overloaded `new`, and there's no way to distinguish them for tagging.

Comment: @walnut  Yes, I've already done both.  e.g. `operator new(std::size_t)` and `operator new(std::size_t, const char* libID, const char* file, uint32_t line)`.  Yes, I could extend that to include another tag.  My initial problem though is that I need to distinguish the STL container allocations coming from the libraries.  So, this could separate the main application from the other libraries, but not separate out what libraries are making the allocations.

Comment: ok, the last part answers my original question. In that case I don't think there is any reliable solution maybe aside from inspecting the call stack in `operator new` to decide the origin of the call.

Comment: No worries.  I appreciate your determination in making sure we weren't miscommunicating.  I have considered looking through something like Google's Breakpad library to figure out a way to get the stackframes, hash them into a value, and use that.  But, that's probably overkill for what we're doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to supplant the default std::allocator for 3rd party libs that don't provide a hook to override the default std::allocator used by STL containers?

Not in general; especially for things that you don't have source code for.

Consider (for example) a call to `std::allocator<int>::allocate`. Chances are, it's marked as `inline`, which means that the body of the function has been embedded in the object code that you're linking. Providing your own copy of that function at link time (or in a separate dylib) will have no effect.

Providing your own global `operator new` is probably the best you can do.

Comment: Yeah, based on what I've found so far, I was afraid that was the answer; but I figured I would ask in case there was something I was missing.

Comment: At least in the case of VS17, they don't appear to mark it as inline: ``` _NODISCARD _DECLSPEC_ALLOCATOR _Ty * allocate(_CRT_GUARDOVERFLOW const size_t _Count)
  { // allocate array of _Count elements
  return (static_cast<_Ty *>(_Allocate<_New_alignof<_Ty>>(_Get_size_of_n<sizeof(_Ty)>(_Count))));
  }
```

Comment: @Paul Functions defined in a class body are `inline` by default and it also doesn't really matter, because `std::allocator` is a class template which results in essentially the same issue as with `inline` if the `std::allocator` specialization is not explicitly specialized.

Comment: @walnut  As I understand it, it is up to the compiler whether or not to make the optimization to inline it.  So while yes, it's a possibility, it's not a given.

Comment: @Paul I am talking about the `inline` specifier. Whether or not the function is inlined is always up to the compiler and not related to `inline`, but if a function is `inline` or a template specialization, then the object code for the function is guaranteed to be present in the library. In any case, the issue pointed out by @MarshallCrow is that the relevant functions *may* be inlined and so there is nothing you can do to change their behavior. `operator new` and `malloc` are special, because they are specifically allowed to be replaced by the C++ and POSIX(?) standards respectively.

Comment: @walnut  So you're saying the `inline` specifier is always implicitly declared for methods where the function is defined inside the class body?

Comment: @Paul Yes, see second sentence on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline.

Comment: @walnut  Thank you for the pointer.  I also just found the question asked and answered here for anyone else following:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/11527505/524597